# Percentage using label

Tags: visual-c#-express-2010

With button + and - percentage varies from 0% to 100%.
  Is there any way to show percentage with label like on this links (images) below.

[image1](http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg19/scaled.php?server=19&filename=85320110.jpg&res=landing)

[image2](http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/1087/100eh.jpg)

PS I don't wont to use progress bar but if there is another better way please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make + and - buttons and a label with that green background.

On click of plus or minus adjust height of label and text on label

```
private void plusButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(percentLength.Height < 100)
        percentLength.Height = percentLength.Height + 10;
}

private void minusButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (percentLength.Height > 0)
        percentLength.Height = percentLength.Height - 10;
}

protected void percentLength_HeightChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    percentLength.Content = percentLength.Height + "%";
}
```

Comment: That works, but I want that label grow up from bottom to top, not from top to bottom

Comment: Set VerticalAlignment="Bottom" for label

Comment: I try this but don't work

`this.percentLength.VerticalAlignment = "Bottom";`

Comment: Set Dock = bottom
VerticalAlignment="Bottom" will work in grid of WPF app
Dock = bottom will work with normal c# app
just chk how to allign bottom in whatso ever you are using